# How to use a Session's value in html?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Suppose I have `Session["myvalue"]` which is integer.
Furthermore- I want to use this value in my HTML code (I want to display this value in the view).

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What you have tried so far ? Also you have to provide your small piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are using MVC then you can go for `@Session["myvalue"]`
- If you are using Asp.net then you can go for `<%:Session["myvalue"].ToString()%>`

Answer (score 0):

To access session in View you can do following thing.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["myvalue"].ToString()
```

if it is object or something then you have to case.

```
   <<your type>> nameofVariable = (<<your type>>)HttpContext.Current.Session["myvalue"]
```

Apart from this you have to check null and everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way

```
<%:Session["myvalue"]%>
```

If you get error then use

```
<%:Session["myvalue"].ToString()%>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use an @ symbol just in front of your session variable and you need to cust the session as an integer like

> @(int)Session["myvalue"]